# nodejs file watch not working on linux

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the Chokidar npm module to establish file watching within my node application.

This is running on an instance that is backed by AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  Essentially, this file watcher is listening to a directory for any files that get added to it.  This works fantastically well on my local dev box (just a windows 10 environment...).  I can move files into the directory, and the file watcher seamlessly picks up the file and does stuff.

So, moving it out to the AWS Linux box is a different story.  Seems to just... not work at all.  I've quadruple checked the file paths to ensure my app configuration matches that of the directory i'm listening too once deployed by EB.

On the linux box, I have a directory which catches some small files:

```
/svr/fileprocessing/post_process
```

then, within the configuration of my node.js application, I have it aimed at this:

```
config.postProcessedDir = '/srv/fileprocessing/post_process/';
```

Then I have the chokidar implementation:

```
stataProcessor.launchPostProcessListener = function () {
    // initialize the file watcher
    chokidar.watch(configuration.postProcessedDir , {
        ignored: /[\/\\]\./,
        awaitWriteFinish: {
            stabilityThreshold: 2000,
            pollInterval: 100
        }
    }).on('add', (file, details) => {
        // console.log(file, path);
        // do cool stuff!
...
...
```

Just can't figure out why it works great locally, but once deployed it just doesn't even get initiated it seems.  I've even gone as far as doing console.log on the entire config file once deployed just to verify everything matches up correctly.  I've written console.logs immediately after the add event just to see if anything fires.  Nothing.  Have also set the custom linux directories to chmod 777 for the sake of testing this thing out.  Still no joy.  I've tried moving a file to the directory with FileZilla as well as being SSH'd into the environment and doing a manual "mv" command.  That didn't work either.

Is there something I'm missing here or not doing correctly?  Any thoughts/suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: Do you commit node_modules or make an npm install on the beanstalk ?

Comment: they install on the beanstalk